# Custom encoding and decoding a string based on tokens

Tags: java, encoding

I am working on a custom encoding and decoding of a string representation of a histogram.

The String contains information about the histogram at the start, and then goes into token and number representation of the bins. The token denotes the details of the length of the bin height and length in the next 'run' of bins. The tokens are A,B,C,D.. etc..

The code below works for many histograms, but i've found a few exceptions which break the code. I have no idea why, and I can't work out if it's the encoding or the decoding that's wrong.. So i'll post both.

There is a lot of code below, if you spot any obvious errors, or possible errors, please let me know.

One of the issues that i'm having is that I can't tell whether it's the encoding or the decoding that's causing the issues. Any ideas on how to distinguish this would be helpful.

I've built a lot of unit tests, and all of them pass, apart from this.

First the code for encoding the string into byte representation It basically works by getting the Token Value, getting the next N digits of the string and converting those to bytes :

```
/** takes in a rawSPEC and returns a byte array to be encoded
 * @param rawSPEC raw SPEC
 * @return byte array
 */
public static byte[] encodeRawSPEC(String rawSPEC){

    //work out the size in advance.
    List<Byte> byteList = new LinkedList<>();

    //loop through the raw string
    int length = 0;
    int height = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < rawSPEC.length(); i++){
        //read the token from the string
        char token = rawSPEC.charAt(i);

        byteList.add((byte)(token & 0xFF));

        //find the length and height in bytes of the valid token
        boolean nonSpecial = false;
        for(Token t : Token.values()){
            if(token == t.name().charAt(0)){
                nonSpecial = true;
                height = t.getHeight();
                length = t.getLength();
            }
        }

        if(nonSpecial) {
            //read the height and length values
            String tokenLength;
            String tokenHeight;
            if (length != 0 && length != 1) {
                if (length == 8) {
                    //1 byte. just convert to byte and add
                    tokenLength = rawSPEC.substring(i + 1, i + 4);
                    i += 3;
                    byteList.add((byte)(Integer.parseInt(tokenLength)));
                } else if (length == 16) {
                    //2 bytes. convert to byte array and add each sequencially
                    tokenLength = rawSPEC.substring(i + 1, i + 6);
                    i += 5;
                    byte[] byt = SPECTools.encode2BitStringDecimal(Integer.parseInt(tokenLength));
                    for(byte b : byt) byteList.add(b);
                } else {
                    //4 bytes. convert to byte array and add each sequencially
                    tokenLength = rawSPEC.substring(i + 1, i + 11);
                    i += 10;
                    byte[] byt = SPECTools.encode4BitStringDecimal(Integer.parseInt(tokenLength));
                    for(byte b : byt) byteList.add(b);
                }

            }

                //encode any heights
            if (height != 0 && height != 1) {
                if (height == 8) {
                    tokenHeight = rawSPEC.substring(i + 1, i + 4);
                    i += 3;
                    byteList.add((byte)(Integer.parseInt(tokenHeight)));
                } else if (height == 16) {
                    tokenHeight = rawSPEC.substring(i + 1, i + 6);
                    i += 5;
                    byte[] byt = SPECTools.encode2BitStringDecimal(Integer.parseInt(tokenHeight));
                    for(byte b : byt) byteList.add(b);
                } else {
                    tokenHeight = rawSPEC.substring(i + 1, i + 11);
                    i += 10;
                    byte[] byt = SPECTools.encode4BitStringDecimal(Integer.parseInt(tokenHeight));
                    for(byte b : byt) byteList.add(b);
                }

            }

        }else if(token == 'R'){
            String numReads = rawSPEC.substring(i+1, i+4);
            byteList.add((byte)(Integer.parseInt(numReads)));
            i+=3;
            int reads = Integer.parseInt(numReads);
            for(int j = 0; j < reads; j++){
                String h = rawSPEC.substring(i+1, i+4);
                i+=3;
                byteList.add((byte)(Integer.parseInt(h)));
            }
        }else if(token == 'S'){
            String numReads = rawSPEC.substring(i+1, i+4);
            int a = Integer.parseInt(numReads);
            byteList.add((byte)(Integer.parseInt(numReads)));

            i+=3;
            int reads = Integer.parseInt(numReads);
            for(int j = 0; j < reads; j++){
                String h = rawSPEC.substring(i+1, i+6);
                i+=5;
                byte[] byt = SPECTools.encode2BitStringDecimal(Integer.parseInt(h));
                for(byte b : byt) byteList.add(b);
            }
        }else if(token == 'T') {
            String h = rawSPEC.substring(i + 1, i + 11);
            i += 10;
            byte[] byt = SPECTools.encode4BitStringDecimal(Integer.parseInt(h));
            for (byte b : byt) byteList.add(b);
            h = rawSPEC.substring(i + 1, i + 11);
            i += 10;
            byt = SPECTools.encode4BitStringDecimal(Integer.parseInt(h));
            for (byte b : byt) byteList.add(b);
        }else if(token == 'U'){
            String h = rawSPEC.substring(i + 1, i + 11);
            i += 10;
            byte[] byt = SPECTools.encode4BitStringDecimal(Integer.parseInt(h));
            for (byte b : byt) byteList.add(b);
        }else if(token == 'V'){
            for(int j = i; j < rawSPEC.length(); j++){
                if(rawSPEC.charAt(j) == '0' && rawSPEC.charAt(j+1) == '0' && rawSPEC.charAt(j+1) == '0'){
                    String h = rawSPEC.substring(i+1, j);
                    for(char c : h.toCharArray()){
                        byteList.add((byte)(c & 0xFF));
                    }
                    i += h.length();

                    byteList.add((byte)0);
                    i+=3;


                    break;
                }
            }
        }else if(token == 'W'){
            //encode the 6 escape characters
            for(int j = 0; j < 6; j ++){
                String numReads = rawSPEC.substring(i+1, i+4);
                byteList.add((byte)(Integer.parseInt(numReads)));
                i+=3;
            }

            //encode the 4 Bit number
            String number = rawSPEC.substring(i + 1, i + 11);
            i += 10;
            byte[] byt = SPECTools.encode4BitStringDecimal(Integer.parseInt(number));
            for(byte b : byt) byteList.add(b);

        }else if(token == 'X'){
            //code
            String code = rawSPEC.substring(i+1, i+4);
            byteList.add((byte)(Integer.parseInt(code)));
            i+=3;

            //statement
            String statementLength = rawSPEC.substring(i+1, i+4);
            int leng = Integer.parseInt(statementLength);
            i+=3;
            byteList.add((byte)(leng));
            for(int j = i+1; j < i+1 + leng; j++){
                byteList.add((byte)rawSPEC.charAt(j));
            }
            i+=leng;

            //extension
            String extension = rawSPEC.substring(i+1, i+6);
            byte[] b = SPECTools.encode2BitStringDecimal(Integer.parseInt(extension));
            for(byte by: b ){
                byteList.add(by);
            }
            i+=5;
            //endseq
            int endLength = (Integer.parseInt(rawSPEC.substring(i+1, i+4)));
            byteList.add((byte) endLength);
            i+=3;
            if(endLength != 0){
                for(int j = i+1; j < i+1 + endLength; j++){
                    byteList.add((byte)rawSPEC.charAt(j));
                }
                i+=endLength;
            }

            //endseq
            int flankLength = (Integer.parseInt(rawSPEC.substring(i+1, i+4)));
            byteList.add((byte) flankLength);
            i+=3;
            if(flankLength != 0){
                for(int j = i+1; j < i+1 + flankLength; j++){
                    byteList.add((byte)rawSPEC.charAt(j));
                }
                i+=flankLength;
            }


        }else if(token == 'Y'){
            //must be Y
            String Ybit = rawSPEC.substring(i + 1, i + 11);
            i += 10;
            byte[] byt = SPECTools.encode4BitStringDecimal(Integer.parseInt(Ybit));
            for(byte b : byt) byteList.add(b);
        }
    }

    //convert to array
    byte[] byteArray = new byte[byteList.size()];
    for(int i = 0; i < byteList.size(); i++) byteArray[i] = byteList.get(i);

    return byteArray;

}
```

Secondly, the decoding code. Works the other way, grabs the token. Gets the appropriate number of bytes, then converts the bytes to the integer and appends to string:

```
public static char[] decodeBinarySPECtoRAW(byte[] bytes){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        int height = 0;
        int length = 0;
        int histogramLength = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
                char token = (char) bytes[i];

                sb.append(token);
                boolean nonSpecial = false;
                for (Token t : Token.values()) {
                    if (token == t.name().charAt(0)) {
                        nonSpecial = true;
                        height = t.getHeight();
                        length = t.getLength();
                    }
                }

                if (nonSpecial) {
                    //length
                    if (length != 0 && length != 1) {
                        if (length == 8) {
                            //1 byte
                            sb.append(String.format("%03d", bytes[i + 1] & 0xFF));
                            histogramLength+=bytes[i+1] & 0xFF;
                            i++;
                        } else if (length == 16) {
                            //2 bytes
                            histogramLength+= SPECTools.convertFromByteArray2(bytes[i + 1], bytes[i + 2]);
                            sb.append(String.format("%05d", SPECTools.convertFromByteArray2(bytes[i + 1], bytes[i + 2])));
                            i += 2;
                        } else {
                            //4 bytes
                            histogramLength += SPECTools.convertFromByteArray4(bytes[i + 1], bytes[i + 2], bytes[i + 3], bytes[i + 4]);
                            sb.append(String.format("%010d", SPECTools.convertFromByteArray4(bytes[i + 1], bytes[i + 2], bytes[i + 3], bytes[i + 4])));
                            i += 4;
                        }
                    }else{
                        histogramLength++;
                    }

                    //height
                    if (height != 0 && height != 1) {
                        if (height == 8) {
                            //1 byte
                            sb.append(String.format("%03d", bytes[i + 1] & 0xFF));
                            i++;
                        } else if (height == 16) {
                            //2 bytes
                            sb.append(String.format("%05d", SPECTools.convertFromByteArray2(bytes[i + 1], bytes[i + 2])));
                            i += 2;
                        } else {
                            //4 bytes
                            sb.append(String.format("%010d", SPECTools.convertFromByteArray4(bytes[i + 1], bytes[i + 2], bytes[i + 3], bytes[i + 4])));
                            i += 4;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    switch (token) {
                        case 'R': {
                            int numReads = (int)bytes[i + 1];
                            i++;
                            sb.append(String.format("%03d", numReads & 0xFF));
                            for (int j = 0; j < numReads; j++) {
                                int nextNum = bytes[i + 1];
                                sb.append(String.format("%03d", nextNum & 0xFF));
                                histogramLength++;
                                i++;
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                        case 'S': {
                            int numReads = (int)bytes[i + 1];
                            i++;
                            sb.append(String.format("%03d", numReads & 0xFF));
                            for (int j = 0; j < numReads; j++) {
                                histogramLength++;

                                int in = SPECTools.convertFromByteArray2(bytes[i + 1], bytes[i + 2]);
                                sb.append(String.format("%05d", in));
                                i += 2;

                            }
                            break;
                        }
                        case 'T': {
                            sb.append(String.format("%010d", SPECTools.convertFromByteArray4(bytes[i + 1], bytes[i + 2], bytes[i + 3], bytes[i + 4])));
                            i += 4;
                            sb.append(String.format("%010d", SPECTools.convertFromByteArray4(bytes[i + 1], bytes[i + 2], bytes[i + 3], bytes[i + 4])));
                            i += 4;
                            break;
                        }
                        case 'U': {
                            sb.append(String.format("%010d", SPECTools.convertFromByteArray4(bytes[i + 1], bytes[i + 2], bytes[i + 3], bytes[i + 4])));
                            i += 4;
                            break;
                        }
                        case 'V': {
                            List<Byte> VBytes = new ArrayList<>();
                            boolean escapeFound = false;
                            while (!escapeFound) {
                                if( i + 1< bytes.length) {
                                    if ( bytes[i + 1] == 0) escapeFound = true;
                                    else {
                                        VBytes.add(bytes[i + 1]);
                                        i += 1;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            for (byte b : VBytes) {
                                sb.append((char) b);
                            }
                            sb.append(String.format("%03d", bytes[i + 1] & 0xFF));
                            i += 1;
                            break;
                        }
                        case 'W': {
                            for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
                                sb.append(String.format("%03d", bytes[i + 1]));
                                i += 1;
                            }
                            sb.append(String.format("%010d", SPECTools.convertFromByteArray4(bytes[i + 1], bytes[i + 2], bytes[i + 3], bytes[i + 4])));
                            i += 4;
                            break;
                        }
                        case 'X': {
                            sb.append(String.format("%03d", bytes[i + 1] & 0xFF));
                            i += 1;
                            //get length of the statement
                            int statementLength = bytes[i + 1] & 0xFF;
                            sb.append(String.format("%03d", statementLength));
                            i += 1;
                            for (int j = i + 1; j < i + 1 + statementLength; j++) {
                                sb.append((char) bytes[j]);
                            }
                            i += statementLength;

                            sb.append(String.format("%05d", SPECTools.convertFromByteArray2(bytes[i + 1], bytes[i + 2])));
                            i += 2;
                            //endseq
                            int endLength = bytes[i + 1];
                            sb.append(String.format("%03d", endLength));
                            i += 1;
                            if (endLength != 0) {
                                for (int j = i + 1; j < i + 1 + endLength; j++) {
                                    sb.append((char) bytes[j]);
                                }
                                i += endLength;
                            }

                            //flankseq
                            int flankLength = bytes[i + 1];
                            sb.append(String.format("%03d", flankLength));
                            i += 1;
                            if (flankLength != 0) {
                                for (int j = i + 1; j < i + 1 + flankLength; j++) {
                                    sb.append((char) bytes[j]);
                                }
                                i += flankLength;
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                        case 'Y': {
                            //must be Y
                            sb.append(String.format("%010d", SPECTools.convertFromByteArray4(bytes[i + 1], bytes[i + 2], bytes[i + 3], bytes[i + 4])));
                            i += 4;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

    return sb.toString().toCharArray();
}
```

Finally the test to call it, this includes the string that's breaking the code. AFAIK, the string input generated from the histogram is valid.

```
@Test
public void non_workingsample() throws Exception{

    String sample = "T00000000010000000001VTEL_Telomeric_repeat_Mus_musculus000X000008pu1.AE.100001000000W0000000000000000000000000101Y0000001236M00705I106I022I010I007I018I002I014I012EI004I020I006I011I004F002R028004007004008036012001017010007087005007010005008053001008003010005032000009003005007F002R019006002010004001000010006002004001000014004007003000001007J002004I007B002R010003001009007001003006002004006B002R010008000006005002000005006009010F002R007009004006005002000008J002005R053004002001005000006008044010006002004002039006009002012009046011012004009002046008013002010005067002012002007001042004010003011003040004006002011007025001014001J002006R017016004005003012006011000006002006005004001006001008J002003R009001014002006005000002007002J002005R038003002004002008011003001003001012004003000002003013004001000006000008006003001005002005010003002007000009003004002J002004R014005006001002008003006005130003006004006009B002R007001005009005001000006J002002I005B002R016018002007006002000009000005003000002003002004010F002R022004002004003001000007000007008001003006003004006002000005004011002F002R010005004008006000002004000004008J002002R004008002005003B002I006I003J002007R006000001005002011004B002R028004003014003001000009003007010003000006003010008000001006003012009000001008002012006F002I008AI007F003R022004001006011002000011004007005001000007003008004002000010001010006F002J002006I012I009B002R004006003015003J002002R016012004012002001002003002007002001000009005012010B002R014005000011006002000005002024008000006009002J002008R017004002009001009012003000005003004002003000010003005J002004S096000010000400003000060000900011000010000700002000070001700009000020001000002000050000800011000100000700006000370266000176000650021600022001050059100250000950002900091002720040900384002580024600104001490062400445001350006500185001730037500322002530004600149001710036700317001500004600104001790047300405001510005900090001640032100329001280003000073001580032100390001000003200076001070028600327013140004900103001380035300314002340004500208001830051000486002340000900003000180000100004J002002AI002EB002EB003F002B003I002B012S042000030000100002000070002401180006020016000658006480119001936003840008700339003650050200471002680004400234001750027301298002280010200226002780043100748010770024400997009950194303337000180001000003001410001100017B004I003I008M01730AI004I002I006F002AI004J002007R010013001003106006025022011001017B005S02500146000130016700336008750098100406000930000200454010770103600995002660000401095021900254000021000020000300047000080001500004J002002R010004005007003000003002007009005J002003R011006041025001000005024021013005004F002S19300011000030006700089001710046800302001190004600173002720041300314001220008400215003980056600636001460006600193003020044900399001240012300192002910051600427001450008700327003630064900523002040010900248003910068700605003500536300550007280137502166001800010300208009770054501811001290009400182002680051300382027310010200193002550050700388003330066000504006090123801354000060000200004000720000701363000060000000002000050000600998000020000000004000030001303781000070000000009000020001800015000040000800006000110002400009000050000100000000030000600807000630016100239004590051900283000740021600337005320080600300000880022200330006500076200363000870023600333006300077500349000930091600323005790082400391001160034500404008010227700833002490064200872019740071900287000850022400368005510074800302000780020600334006240071500313000640023500327007841768101020002910086701185023660031500012000030000500132000050100500002000030000100002000090000200005000000000100005000040629100006J002005I016I013M00268I008I005I008I010I021I007B002W0000000000000000000000472967S13900008000370001400498005110137801226005040015600006005010108901306004630015600002004610104801417004480011700006005810111601281004800013200003005230121601281004870011200001021010110601316004670016900003006400111401467129590012900005004960098904763004860014700005005540114201387004640012400007004880115801238004850015200006004560111701718005260014200004004810133403533004840015100003004230144104702004970014000006005260142401264005850011400004005190110601801004650013400005004560116401302004630012700010005880116501253004490011300008005850104110574004750010300007002750062405034014690007600006002270055200667001820007700004002450046500565002170006000001002240050404887002150008100002000310004500023J002010R014007008005006000007004003005009001004000001J002002R008000006002004003004000006B005I010B003EAI009EI002AF002R007005001000001002000005F002B003I006EB004I007EJ002002F002I005EB007EB002I007B005EB027I047B009M26433B004EB005Z0000081801B003M04952B002M02159000000000000000000";

    byte[] b = APUChunkEncoder.encodeRawSPEC(sample);

    //debugging
    for(byte d : b){
        System.out.println((char) d + " " + (int)d);
    }

    char[] result = APUChunkDecoder.decodeBinarySPECtoRAW(b);


    assertEquals(sample, String.valueOf(result));
}
```

The result of the test:

```
T00000000010000000001VTEL_Telomeric_repeat_Mus_musculus000X000008pu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ﾫ ￔ.w . ﾭ ﾝ:z T00140903820020316796ﾒ B000￁ .￁ﾏ| { ￀ #ﾫﾑ W000071001107001-1190034276044 m ￸ ﾇﾯ]^￳&￘_v|bﾴ g ￐ ￑!ﾁ ^ ﾶ ~ﾫf ￁  ￻ﾄM37889￸aￖJ005006   H0000458835      ￦     
 ￅ           |b            '? ﾡ ￯ ￋJ000216 Q051210036045612X000222 Jﾊ￺kW ￬ Mv]] ﾔCC8ﾇt Yﾔ!￥|bA￹ ﾂhﾶￏU ￠ p'￬.N ￎ Npￋ9@ ￫ GE￼#cﾡ> ;   ﾄ  ￭                ﾓ JII
MI|bII|bI
IIBW       7ﾇSﾋ|b %  ￲bￊ￸ﾜ  ￵Aￏﾜ  ￍﾉ￀u  00581092￠ﾄ  ￀￧p  5|bR$ￓﾩ  ﾀZﾻﾟ2ﾁ  ￰￝ﾛ￦ﾓ  *vk￐|  ￨ﾆￖ￥ﾘ  ￈]ﾶﾎ 000￡6ￍ
￤ﾗ  ﾧﾡ^￱ﾌ  ﾐ￰I002r  R004009007209001ﾆ  ￈ﾌￏ 
 L0042796261004￁q |b I002N04100475g  pﾪﾽL0000393443000(ﾛﾶ M01024 ￵ ￑5￙ <  ￠ ￸ￗ Q005120002031661  J002010R014007008005006000007004003005009001004000001J002002R008000006002004003004000006B005I010B003EAI009EI002AF002R007005001000001002000005F002B003I006EB004I007EJ002002F002I005EB007EB002I007B005EB027I047B009M26433B004EB005Z0000081801B003M04952B002M02159000000000000000000
```

Obviously, some characters aren't being encoded or decoded properly.. But I can't figure out which..

Any ideas or suggestions are very welcome. Thanks.

Edit: Missing parts of the code:

token:

```
/** All lengths and heights in bits.
  * All 1's are to be ignored in writing
  * i.e 1 - 0 is transcoded as A.
  * 1 -1 is transcoded as E
 * 1 - 209 is transcoded as I209
 * 1 - 2 is transcoded as I002 **/
public enum Token {

A (1, 0),
B (8, 0),
C (16,0),
D (32,0),
E (1, 1),
F (8, 1),
G (16,1),
H (32,1),
I (1 ,8),
J (8, 8),
K (16,8),
L (32,8),
M (1,16),
N (8,16),
O (16,16),
P (32,16),
Q (16,32),
Z (1,32);


private final int length;
private final int height;


Token(int length, int height) {
    this.length = length;
    this.height = height;
}

public int getLength() {
    return length;
}

public int getHeight() {
    return height;
}

 }
```

Spectools, just a helper class:

```
public class SPECTools {

public static byte[] encode2BitStringDecimal(int i) {
    byte[] result = new byte[2];
    result[0] = (byte) (i & 0xFF);
    result[1] = (byte) ((i >> 8) & 0xFF);
    return result;
}

public static byte[] encode4BitStringDecimal(int i) {
    byte[] result = new byte[4];
    result[0] = (byte) (i >> 24 & 0xFF);
    result[1] = (byte) (i >> 16 & 0xFF);
    result[2] = (byte) (i >> 8 & 0xFF);
    result[3] = (byte) (i & 0xFF) ;
    return result;
}

public static int convertFromByteArray2(byte byte1, byte byte2){
    return (byte2 & 0xFF) << 8 | (byte1 & 0xFF);
}

public static int convertFromByteArray4(byte byte1, byte byte2, byte byte3, byte byte4){
    return byte1 << 24 | (byte2 & 0xFF) << 16 | (byte3 & 0xFF) << 8 | (byte4 & 0xFF);
}

}
```

Comment: This is from one side way too much code to debug, from the other side it's not the complete code (what's `Token`, for instance).

Comment: I'll post the missing parts

Comment: You test encoding and decoding at once. Test them separately. You will need to calculate the result of the encoding through alternative means - even manually if there are no other options. But this will help you to understand where the error is.

Comment: Next, the test you've posted tests on a huge input. Try reducing it as much as possible. Most probably you'll be able to reproduce the problem in a much shorter input - and this will give you a hint, what's wrong.

Comment: I have separate tests for encoding and decoding must shorter inputs which all pass. It's a long example because it's a complete example of a histogram, and is the only bit that's failing. I'll try to identify the part of the string which is failing.

Comment: LOL. I spend 2 days racking my brains, post it to SO and solve it in 5 mins. It was missing '& 0xFF' on the 'S' and 'R' tokens - since i'm using unsigned ints.